# Автоматическая генерация полей формы

Tags: php, laravel, генерация-случайных-данных

Всем привет! Laravel 5.7

Предыстория: у меня на главной странице есть кнопка, нажав на неё открывается окно с формой:

```
<form action="{{ route('home::number', $item->id_auto ?? "") }}" method="post">
    {{ csrf_field() }}

<label for="">Логин</label>
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="login " value="{{ $item->login ?? "" }}"
       placeholder="Введите свой логин" required=""><br>

<label for="">Ваш id</label>
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="id_auto " value="{{ $item->id_auto ?? "" }}" readonly="">
<br>

<label for="">Ваш пароль</label>
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="password_auto " value="{{ $item->password_auto ?? '' }}" readonly="">
<br>

<hr/>

<input class="btn btn-danger w-100" type="submit" value="Перейти">

</form>
```

Чего бы я хотел: я бы хотел, чтобы нажав на кнопку открытия формы id и пароль уже были автоматически сгенерированы и показаны клиенту.

Как мне это сделать?

Я пробовал сделать функцию генерации в моделях, но она срабатывает только после отправления данных на сервер, т. е. вводить как бы ничего не нужно, поля оставляешь пустыми и потом в личном кабинете смотришь пароль и id. Пробовал создать и подключить новый файл с генерацией, но, чтобы он сработал, нужно сделать кнопку "Сгенерировать" под полем. Это, конечно, тоже не плохо, но я бы хотел, чтобы нажав на кнопку, далее никуда не надо было тыкать, уже был виден свой пароль и свой id.

P. s. для данного вопроса, вряд ли нужно предоставлять контроллеры и модели, поэтому сначала без них, но если будет нужно я мигом)

P. s. s. для тех, кто не телепат, я вроде ясно объяснил, чего я хочу))

Comment: Попробуйте сгенерировать это в контроллере и отправить эти два поля в ваше представление. Так же не забывайте о последующей валидации отправленных данных, в том числе и этих двух полей.

Comment: Хорошо, я попробую, думаю, должно сработать, спасибо. 
Если у кого-то есть еще предложения - пуляйте)